# Проблемы с командой dd

Tags: hdd

Здравствуйте товарищи.После ввода команды  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdb моя флешка перестала работать(команда  fdisk -l  не выводит dev/sdb  ) винда и любой другой дистрибутив ее тоже не видит(работал под ubuntu 10.04).До этого все работало

Comment: наверное вы говорите о том, что при вставке вообше отсутствует блок-девайс?Что выводит     lsusbвозможно проблема с аппаратной частью (больше нет микросхемы или больше нет сторажда). В любом таком случае для меня восстановить работоспособность сложнее, чем купить новую.

Answer (score 4):

Так вы нулями затерли все на вашей флешке, в том числе и таблицу разделов которая находится в первых 512 байтах. Командой

> fdisk /dev/sdb

Попадете в режим разметки вашей флешки, потом нажмете m для справки, либо сразу n для создания нового раздела, далее укажите номер, размер и т.д, ну и после того как вам скажут что раздел создан, нажмите w что бы сохранить изменения.

Answer (score 3):

Либо можете использовать gparted, он намного проще. Может быть вам будет удобнее.